# How to create a pivot table from multiple pivot tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have to create a pivot table that shows different numbers for 2014, 2015 and 2016. Data for a new pivot table is actually based on 3 different, separate pivot tables (each of it has a really really big raw data behind it, around 300000 excel rows per year). is there a way to combine these 3 pivots and create a completely new one where i can filter years etc. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is something like this a good idea: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Comment: It depends partly on the level of detail you want in the new pivot table. You can only pick up the detail in the three intermediate tables. So for example, if you have averages in the intermediate ones and you try to create an average across three years in the final pivot you'll have an "average of averages" issue. More detail in your question would help.

Comment: Why not simply copy the values of three pivot tables into a different cells and then run Pivot Table on that range? Alternatively, append all raw data rows into one data source and pivot that. This might require storing data outside Excel due to million row limit.

Comment: @Vityata this is great, but I dont have the same column and raw names, they`ve changed during the years. But maybe I can change in the the raw data and create the same pivot tables for 2014 2015 and 16 and then use this method.@Doug Glancy I have 3 different pivots (master files in different excel wbooks) showing the same booking numbers for different regions.I have to create a new one where I only have to show numbers eg for Austria for 2014/15 and 16 so my manager can get an overview in one table and not to open 3 big master files and compare by himself.

Comment: @Parfait friend of mine told me that as well, but he mentioned i can create a database using sql...